# Как передать state в this.props.children. React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Привет.
Не знаю как при загрузке с помощью react-router какогото layaut-а передать state в this.props.children.

Вот компонент Children:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class Children extends Component{

    render() {
        return React.cloneElement(this.props.children)
    }
}
```

вот часть компонента App где он загружается:

```
render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Header 
          {...this.state}
          popup={this.handlePopup}
          changeLogin={this.handleUser}
          submitLogin={this.login}
          logout={this.logOut}/>

                <Children children={this.props.children} appState={this.state}/>

                <Footer />
                <Popup 
          {...this.state} 
          changePopup={this.handlePopup}
          selectChange={this.selectChange}
          changeInfoPopup={this.changeInfoPopup}
          changeRadio={this.changeRadio}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
```

вот роутинг:

```
import React from 'react';
import {IndexRoute, Route} from 'react-router';

import App from './layouts/app';
import Body from './layouts/body';
import TwoCols from './layouts/twoCols';

import PersonalArea from './containers/user/PersonalArea'

const routes = (
     <Route path='/' component={App}>

        <Route component={Body}>
            <Route component={TwoCols}>

                <Route path="scz_:user" component={PersonalArea} />  {/*сюда надо перенести state*/}

            </Route>

        </Route>

      </Route>
)

export default routes;
```

Comment: 1) по хорошему надо бы App вынести на уровень выше над роутером, а из него уже и передавать состояние куда угодно ниже 2) совсем по хорошему это тот случай когда лучше подключить redux или mobx и решить проблему раз и навсегда 3) однако если уж следовать имеющемуся подходу...

Comment: кстати Route не может иметь только что-то одно: 1) children 2) component 3) render

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://codesandbox.io/s/03zrxm02yl, но лучшу воспользоваться походом 1 или 2 из моего комментария выше

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

const Header = () => null;
const Footer = () => null;
const Popup = () => null;
const Body = () => null;
const TwoCols = () => null;
const PersonalArea = ({ test }) => test;

type AppProps = {
  children: Function;
};

class App extends React.Component<AppProps, {}> {

  state = { test: 1 }

  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        <Header />

        {
          // @ts-ignore
          this.props.children(this.state)
        }

        <Footer />
        <Popup />
      </div>
    );
  }

}


const Router = props => (
  <div>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Route path='/' render={() => (
        <App>
          { state => (
            <Route
              path="/"
              render={() => <PersonalArea {...state} />}
            />
          )}
        </App>
      )} />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </div>
);

render(<Router />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Сейчас я использовал немножко другой способ но тоже похожий на ваш. 
https://codepen.io/simon1400/pen/rpxabo

Comment: Props передается, но сейчас появилась другая проблема. Когда рендерится компонент PersonalArea то props передается аж через 3 layaut-а, это забирает время и происходит скачки контента на страницу изза того что страница отрендерилась а props еще не загрузились. когда загружаются то все прыгает.

Comment: Думал решить это добавлением прелоадера но пока не нашел способа как в этом случаи добавить прелоадер. Вы не знаете?

Comment: В том-то и беда, что при таком подходе (стейт вехнего компонента гуляет через всю иерархию) ожидается беда с производительностью. Так как любое изменение будет перерисовывать весь сайт полностью. Прелоадер тут видимо не поможет, так как мы не знаем, когда закончился рендеринг (без лишних сложностей по крайней мере), да и собственно - рендеринг только тогда и начнётся, когда прелоадер будет заменён на основную иерархию компонентов. Прелоадер хорошо, когда ждём данные с сервера и т.п.

Также ещё один минус такого подхода - все компонены получаются слишком умные, то есть знают по существование

Comment: некого состояния, что будет приводить к массивному рефакторингу, каждый раз, когда сигнатура состояния (то его его интерфейс или тип в терминах тайпскрипта) меняется.

Поэтому я бы советовал воспользоваться решениями, которыми все и пользуются, а именно редакс или мобх. 

Также разделить приложение на контейнеры (умные компоненты) и компоненты (то есть тупые компоненты). - Об это написано хорошо в документацию в рекдаксу, но подход универсальный.

Надеюсь я правильно понял проблему с задержкой рендеринга. Хотя не очень понял, как это оно "всё прыгает", с таким я в реакте не сталкивался

Comment: А что Вы имеет в виду говоря "props ещё не загрузились"? Там что-то идёт асинхронно с сервера? Тогда можно добавить прелоадер, нужно в стейт добавить `loading: boolean = true` , и в App или в роутере выводить компонент-спиннер вместе основного контента, а когда данные загрузились менять loading на false

Comment: Понял по поводу редакса но не хотелось бы сейчас все переделывать. Сайт большой. А начал уже все делать таким способом. Понимаю что моя ошибка что не смотрел на перед.
Может например как решение в App записывать state в сессию а при открытии внутренней страницы брать данные из объекта сессии?
Конечно костыли выходят)

Comment: Ну у меня передается state из App в PersonalArea например имя пользователя. Когда редерится PersonalArea то сначала заредерится весь компонент с пустым местом там где должно быть имя а потом подгружаются props и появляется имя на том месте, вот так и прыгает контент весь.

Comment: Соответственно имя берется при логине с базы данных, и записывается в state лаяута App. оттуда передается по всем компонентам.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70406/discussion-between-dimmi-and-daniel-khoroshko).